# Best way to serialize composite - (design pattern)

Tags: java, serialization, design-patterns, composite

I have following java code that is implementation of Composite Design pattern:

```
//composite designed for type safety (all Leaf-only operations only in leaf)
interface Component extends Visitable {
  void enable();
  void disable();
}

class CompositeA implements Component {
  private String compositeData;
  private boolean enabled;
  private Set<Component> components = new HashSet<>();

  CompositeA(String compositeData) {
    this.compositeData = compositeData;
  }

  void addChild(Component component){
    this.components.add(component);
  }

  String getCompositeData() {
    return compositeData;
  }

  Set<Component> getComponents() {
    return components;
  }

  @Override
  public void enable() {
    this.enabled = true;
  }

  @Override
  public void disable() {
    this.enabled = false;
  }

  @Override
  public Object accept(ComponentVisitor visitor) {
    return visitor.visit(this);
  }
}

class CompositeB implements Component{
  private int compositeData;
  private boolean enabled;
  private Set<Component> components = new HashSet<>();

  CompositeB(int compositeData) {
    this.compositeData = compositeData;
  }

  void addChild(Component component){
    this.components.add(component);
  }

  int getCompositeData() {
    return compositeData;
  }

  Set<Component> getComponents() {
    return components;
  }

  @Override
  public void enable() {
    this.enabled = true;
  }

  @Override
  public void disable() {
    this.enabled = false;
  }

  @Override
  public Object accept(ComponentVisitor visitor) {
    return visitor.visit(this);
  }
}

class Leaf implements Component {
  private boolean enabled;
  private String[] leafData;

  Leaf(String[] leafData) {
    this.leafData = leafData;
  }

  String[] getLeafData() {
    return leafData;
  }

  @Override
  public void enable() {
    this.enabled = true;
  }

  @Override
  public void disable() {
    this.enabled = false;
  }

  @Override
  public Object accept(ComponentVisitor visitor) {
    return visitor.visit(this);
  }
}
```

There are 2 possible composite roots here (`CompositeA` and `CompositeB`) and one leaf component (`Leaf`).

Here I define DTOs that will hold serialized data:

```
class WholeCompositeASerialized {                     
  String content;                                     
  List<Object> serializedChildren;                    
}                                                     
                                                      
class WholeCompositeBSerialized{                      
  String content;                                     
  List<Object> serializedChildren;                    
}                                                     
                                                      
class WholeLeafSerialized{                            
  String content;                                     
}
```

Now if I use visitor pattern for serialization, I get something like this:

```
interface ComponentVisitor {
  WholeCompositeASerialized visit(CompositeA compositeA);
  WholeCompositeBSerialized visit(CompositeB compositeB);
  WholeLeafSerialized visit(Leaf leaf);
}

class SerializableComponentVisitor implements ComponentVisitor{
  @Override
  public WholeCompositeASerialized visit(CompositeA compositeA) {
    WholeCompositeASerialized wcas = new WholeCompositeASerialized();
    wcas.serializedChildren = compositeA
        .getComponents()
        .stream()
        .map(c -> c.accept(this))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
    wcas.content = compositeA.getCompositeData();
    return wcas;
  }

  @Override
  public WholeCompositeBSerialized visit(CompositeB compositeB) {
    WholeCompositeBSerialized wcbs = new WholeCompositeBSerialized();
    wcbs.serializedChildren = compositeB
        .getComponents()
        .stream()
        .map(c -> c.accept(this))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
    wcbs.content = String.valueOf(compositeB.getCompositeData());
    return wcbs;
  }

  @Override
  public WholeLeafSerialized visit(Leaf leaf) {
    WholeLeafSerialized wls = new WholeLeafSerialized();
    wls.content = Arrays.toString(leaf.getLeafData());
    return wls;
  }
}

interface Visitable{
  Object accept(ComponentVisitor visitor);
}
```

and if I use `instanceof` this is the code that does the same thing:

```
class SerializerUsingInstanceOf {
  Object decide(Component component){
    if(component instanceof CompositeA){
      return serialize((CompositeA)component);
    }
    else if(component instanceof CompositeB){
      return serialize((CompositeB)component);
    }
    else{
      return serialize((Leaf)component);
    }
  }

  WholeCompositeASerialized serialize(CompositeA compositeA) {
    WholeCompositeASerialized wcas = new WholeCompositeASerialized();
    wcas.serializedChildren = compositeA
        .getComponents()
        .stream()
        .map(this::decide)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
    wcas.content = compositeA.getCompositeData();
    return wcas;
  }

  WholeCompositeBSerialized serialize(CompositeB compositeB) {
    WholeCompositeBSerialized wcbs = new WholeCompositeBSerialized();
    wcbs.serializedChildren = compositeB
        .getComponents()
        .stream()
        .map(this::decide)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
    wcbs.content = String.valueOf(compositeB.getCompositeData());
    return wcbs;
  }

  WholeLeafSerialized serialize(Leaf leaf) {
    WholeLeafSerialized wls = new WholeLeafSerialized();
    wls.content = Arrays.toString(leaf.getLeafData());
    return wls;
  }
}
```

I guess also that visitor is preferred here because when we add new `Component`, we are required to implement `Object accept(ComponentVisitor visitor)` method also - so we cannot forget that we need a code for serialization of this new component. If we do the same when we use `instanceof` we would possibly forget to add it to that check.

Now - my question is - is there any way that we can get rid of that ugly `Object` return type in `Object accept(ComponentVisitor visitor)` method signature? The only other option that comes to my mind is to use some marker interface (eg. `interface SerializedComponent {}`) and then have all serializer classes implement that empty interface like this `class WholeCompositeASerialized implements SerializedComponent` but it still does not seem right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the proper way could be to use generics here.

e.g. https://onlinegdb.com/r1m5Eg4DP

```
public class Main {

     public static void main(String []args){
        ComponentVisitor<SerializedComponent> serializer = new ComponentSerializer();
        Component componentA = new ComponentA();
        SerializedComponent serializedA = componentA.accept(serializer);
        System.out.println(serializedA);
        
        Component component = new ComponentB();
        SerializedComponent serializedB = component.accept(serializer);
        System.out.println(serializedB);
     }
     
     static interface Component {
        public <V> V accept(ComponentVisitor<V> visitor);
     }
     
     static class ComponentA implements Component {
        public <V> V accept(ComponentVisitor<V> visitor) {
            return visitor.visit(this);
        }
     }
     
     static class ComponentB implements Component {
         public <V> V accept(ComponentVisitor<V> visitor) {
            return visitor.visit(this);
         }
     }
     
     static interface SerializedComponent {}
     
     static class SerializedComponentA implements SerializedComponent {
     }
     
     static class SerializedComponentB implements SerializedComponent {
     }
     
     static interface ComponentVisitor<V> {
        public V visit(ComponentA component);
        public V visit(ComponentB component);
     }
     
     static class ComponentSerializer implements ComponentVisitor<SerializedComponent> {
        public SerializedComponent visit(ComponentA component) {
            return new SerializedComponentA();
        }
        public SerializedComponent visit(ComponentB component) {
            return new SerializedComponentB();
        }
     }
}
```

Comment: The problem that I see here is that visit has to return same `SerializedComponent` object. What happens when I want to serialize `ComponentA` to `SerializedComponentA` and `ComponentB` to `SerializedComponentB`? This is nice in the way that Composite implements `V accept()` instead of `Object accept()`, but i still have to create `ComponentVisitor<Object>`?

Comment: So definitely better than having `Object` inside composite, but is it possible to completely get rid of that `Object`/Marker Interface?

Comment: @MarkoKraljevic Not sure what you mean with the first comment. The sample code does return SerializedA and SerializedB already.

Comment: It returns `SerializedComponent`. So I would need to cast that one manually if I want to forward it to method `printSerializedComponent(SerializedComponentA)`

Comment: @MarkoKraljevic Well you have to return a base type or else the caller must know what type of object it's dealing with beforehand. You could still use a `SerializedComponentVisitor` to print these instead of casting. Same pattern for serialized components.

Comment: Caller will know that since `visit(ComponentA)` should return `WholeCompositeASerialized` etc. And this one works if I do this `class SerializableComponentVisitor implements ComponentVisitor<Object>{
  @Override
  public WholeCompositeASerialized visit(CompositeA compositeA)`, but you can see that I still use that `Object` as generic. In your case, I could actually use `SerializedComponent` marker interface - and I guess this is the best possible solution I can get.

Comment: @MarkoKraljevic Yeah that works. Interfaces can be covariant on the return type like you did and using `SerializedComponent` is probably the best you can get indeed.

Comment: @MarkoKraljevic Did you take my approach?

Comment: Yes, until this (https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/8213076) is fully implemented I guess I have to go this way. `Today, to express ad-hoc polymorphic calculations like this, we would use the "Visitor" pattern. Using pattern matching is generally more transparent and straightforward.`

Comment: Would you mind accepting the answer if you went that route? Thanks. Ill have a look at the issue you referenced.

Answer (score 0):

You are attempting to return concrete type information from the Visitor. This is not the purpose of the pattern. The Visitor encapsulates (and handles) the concrete type internally.

The solution here is to move *all* logic specific to `ComponentA` (or any A-specific type you might convert it to) into the `visit(ComponentA)` method, and likewise for `ComponentB`.

If you don't want the type encapsulation of the Visitor, then a different design is more suitable, such as pattern matching.

---

Comments on the comment...

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Using a concrete type here defeats the purpose of these patterns.
    // Instead, program to an interface:
    // Component c1 = new CompositeA("root");
    CompositeA c1 = new CompositeA("root");
    c1.addChild(new Leaf(new String[]{"leaf11", "leaf12"}));

    CompositeA c2 = new CompositeA("composite1");
    c2.addChild(new Leaf(new String[]{"leaf21", "leaf22"}));
    c1.addChild(c2);

    SerializableComponentVisitor scv = new SerializableComponentVisitor();
    // Clients never invoke visit methods directly,
    //  because they do not have the type information to make these calls.
    // A client would execute, c1.accept(scv)
    WholeCompositeASerialized wcas1 = scv.visit(c1);
}
```

Comment: What is the problem when I use it in this way? https://onlinegdb.com/H1gxCWsEwv For me seems like an OK solution -> I just override SerializationMarkerInterface return type to concrete serialization types that will be produced by the code.

Comment: Visitor is a way to implement pattern matching for languages that dont natively supports it.

Comment: @plalx Pattern matching will be there in one of next Java versions, but still it will use underneath `instanceof` and implicit cast - and I read somewhere that it is not good to use that according to Liskov substitution principle... Now I do not know what are the downsides, but just remember reading that...

Comment: @jaco0646 can you please modify my example here onlinegdb.com/H1gxCWsEwv , since I do not understand what you mean?

Comment: @plalx, yes: Pattern Matching is a Functional design pattern, and Visitor can be described as a bridge from OO to FP. While encapsulation is critical to OO design, FP is more ambivalent about it. I could have said, "If you don't want the encapsulation of OO, then a different paradigm may be more suitable, such as FP." I was thinking of the patterns as representative of their respective paradigms.

Comment: @jaco0646 but what is the problem with encapsulation in the `instanceof` example? I'm only using publicly available getters.

Comment: @jaco0646 the only problem I have with `instanceof` and that is not related to OO design, is that if I in future implement new `ComponentC implements Component`, visitor will complain that I did not implement method inside - so I cannot get it wrong, while I would probably forget to use it in `instanceof` matcher (at least until `permits` keyword for classes is introduced in java).

Comment: @MarkoKraljevic, I think this thread has segued into a new topic, unrelated to serializing a composite. You might search the motivation and purpose of the Visitor Pattern, and/or ask a new question; but there's a bit of an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) here, based on the _assumption_ that Visitor is a solution. You might simply ignore the Visitor pattern and this headache goes away.